# Capturing all followers in tweepy

Tags: python, loops, twitter, tweepy

I want to print all followers or following in twitter:

```
while True:
    try:
       for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers,screen_name='TestUser').items():
            print user.screen_name
       break
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*20)
```

When I run this part it tries to capture following. number of captured user is 200 in my thread. but it doesn't keep continue after 20 minutes sleeping... it tries but it gets captured users again.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're starting all over again in each while-loop iteration as you create a new iterator every time in the `for user in...` line.

Try with a generator:

```
def handle_errors(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            time.sleep(20 * 60)

for user in handle_errors(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers,screen_name='TestUser').items()):
     print user.screen_name
```